# Change selected value of DDSlick dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website, I am using the DDSlick plugin for styling my select dropdown. It is nice. But I can't change the selected value using `javascript`.

For example, if the current selected value is "INDIA", then I want to change "INDIA" to "USA" by using `javascript`, without refreshing the page. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a bit more information, maybe create a http://jsfiddle.net like is it the same dropdown...

Comment: By `changing "INDIA" to "USA"` do you mean you want to avoid that "INDIA" selection and force the user selecting "USA" ?

Comment: @Batu Zet: That means, I have 5 country names in my dropdown. India is selected by default. When click on a button, I need to change INDIA to USA or some other using JavaScript. Is that possible?

Comment: @Arun you mean when you click on a button, you wanna select USA dynamically?

Comment: @Batu Zet: I need to display USA in the place of INDIA as selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want force a specific selected items on click on buttons you culd use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').ddslick({
        width: 300,
        selectText: "Select an item",
        onSelected: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });

    $('#button').on('click', function () {
           $('#dropdown').ddslick('select', {index: 2 });
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>select</option>
    <option id="a" value="">INDIA</option>
    <option id="b" value="">USA</option>
    <option id="c" value="">AFRICA</option>
</select>
<input name="" type="button" value="change" id="button">
</body>
</html>
```

with similar code you can create a button to browse through all the options in the list
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/UX9w2/)
If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Comment: This works except for when the index is 0. Then the option is not shown. This was a bug in 2013 and supposedly fixed but I just started using ddslick a few months ago and am having this problem. The date on the file is 10/31/2014, unfortunately there is no version number.

Comment: @user2822280 : You just need to edit this part of the code as shown [here](https://github.com/neo/ddslick/commit/f83bb4f1d0e6124bd2f00ccff96ae948dec0f936)